# How do i get datediff to work with min() max() on sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Say I have this table:

```
                         EMPLOYEES
----------------------------------------------------------
first    last        ID    hire         terminated    wage
------   ---------   ---   ----------   -----------   ----
Ruth     Halburg     1     2010-05-15   2017-03-01    2000
Sally    Hallson     2     2010-08-20   NULL          5000
Merry    Hallway     3     2011-01-24   NULL          3000
```

and I need to get the difference in days between the max 'hire' date and min 'hire' date of employees still working in the company (terminated = NULL).

I know I need to use something like

```
Select *, datediff(d, max(hire), min(hire) as Difference
From Employees
Where terminated = NULL
```

but i'm not sure how to get it to work.

Comment: change `terminated = NULL` for `terminated IS NULL`

Comment: What's your using DBMS MySQL or MSSQL?

Comment: Tag properly!!!  MySQL <> SQL Server.

Comment: Reverse the min and max arguments.

Comment: Also you might need to add 1 depending on how you are counting days.

Comment: I don't understand why you haven't simply tried your query. Then you would have got some error message, probably "missing closing parenthesis", and corrected this. Then you'd have tried again and either got an error on the datadiff parameters or not, depending on the DBMS you are actually using. In case of an error, you could have checked the function documentation for your DBMS, online or in a book. At last you would have got an empty result. You would either have found out about the mistake with `terminated = NULL` yourself or asked here. But why you haven't gone these steps is beyond me.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using mysql datediff  return difference in days

and for the query

If the terminated is a string the you must check for 'NULL' 
if is a date the you should check for is null

```
  Select  datediff(max(hire), min(hire)) as Difference
  From Employees
  Where terminated = 'NULL'
```

or

```
  Select  datediff( max(hire), min(hire)) as Difference
  From Employees
  Where terminated is null
```

If you want use aggregation function you can't use column in select clause that is not mentioned  in group by eg:

```
select  last, datediff(max(hire), min(hire)) as Difference
From Employees
Where terminated is null
group by  last
```

or

```
select  last, datediff(max(hire), min(hire)) as Difference
From Employees
group by  last
```

for sql-server instead  of datediff(date1, date2)  for day difference you must add the interval  param

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(d, max(hire),min(hire))
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want:

```
Select id,
       datediff(day, min(hire) max(hire)) as Difference
From Employees
group by id
having count(terminated) < count(*) -- at least one NULL value
```

Note that the syntax for `datediff()` uses the SQL Server version of the function.  I don't think this is really important to your question.  The key part is the `group by` and `having` clauses.

Comment: But their sample data only has one row per distinct `id` value so aggregating `hire` based on that doesn't make a great deal of sense. I think the question is currently unclear.